# Does vert.x support websocket using stomp over sockjs like Spring4?

Tags: spring, websocket, vert.x, stomp, sockjs

Does vert.x support websocket using stomp over sockjs like Spring4?

Spring4 websocket support stomp over sockjs, but I don't found in Vert.x document  about stomp over sockjs, only stomp with websocket:
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-stomp/java/#_using_the_stomp_server_with_web_sockets.

Comment: sockjs is the STOMP implementation in JavaScript, spring is Java, you can build a Vert.x STOMP server and a client using sockjs, what are you asking exactly?

Comment: Spring websocket support using Stomp.js over sockjs, and Spring 
 Sockjs Server use Stomp as a sub protocol, client js code can be like this: var socket = new SockJS("/spring-websocket-portfolio/portfolio");
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);  So I want to know does Vert.x  support like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Vert.x 3.5.1 it is not supported. Can you please [file a feature request](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-stomp/issues/new) in the `vertx-stomp` project? Thanks

Comment: I was not familiar with Vert.x before, I think eventbus can do similar work.

Comment: @tkec yes it can. If there's no hard requirement for STOMP then yes, the event bus browser bridge is the alternative.